# Angular2 Custom HTTP wrapper request resend not working

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, angular2-http

I have a written a custom HTTP wrapper to implement OAuth2 in Angular2 here is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, Request, BaseRequestOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { API_BASE, AUTH_TOKEN_LS_KEY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_PASS, LOCAL_STORAGE_USER_KEY } from 'config/constants';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService 
{
    token: any;

    constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router) {}

    get(url: string):Observable<Response> {
        return this.request(API_BASE+url, RequestMethod.Get);
    }

    post(url:string, body:any):Observable<Response> {
        return this.request(API_BASE+url, RequestMethod.Post, body);
    }

    put(url:string, body:any):Observable<Response> {
        return this.request(API_BASE+url, RequestMethod.Put, body);
    }

    patch(url:string, body:any):Observable<Response> {
        return this.request(API_BASE+url, RequestMethod.Patch, body);
    }

    delete(url: string):Observable<Response> {
        return this.request(API_BASE+url, RequestMethod.Delete);
    }

    head(url: string):Observable<Response> {
        return this.request(API_BASE+url, RequestMethod.Head);
    }

    options(url: string):Observable<Response> {
        return this.request(API_BASE+url, RequestMethod.Options);
    }

    private request(url:string, method:RequestMethod, body?:any):Observable<Response> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.createBearerTokenHeader(headers);
        this.createContentTypeHeader(headers);

        let options = new BaseRequestOptions();
        options.headers = headers;
        options.url = url;
        options.method = method;
        options.body = body;

        let requestOptions = {url: url, method: method, body: body};
        let request = new Request(options);
        return this.intercept(this.http.request(request), requestOptions);
    }

    private intercept(observable: Observable<Response>, requestOptions: any): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            if( err.status == 401 ) {
                this.refreshToken().subscribe(result => {
                    if( result == true ) {
                        return this.request(requestOptions.url, requestOptions.method, requestOptions.body);
                    } else {
                        localStorage.removeItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_USER_KEY);
                        localStorage.removeItem(AUTH_TOKEN_LS_KEY);
                        this.router.navigate(['/']);
                    }
                });

                return Observable.empty();
            }

            return Observable.throw(err);
        });
    }

    refreshToken(): Observable<boolean> {
        this.token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_LS_KEY));
        let refreshToken = this.token.refresh;
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.createBearerTokenHeader(headers);
        return this.http.post(API_BASE+'/auth/default/login', {
                grant_type: "refresh_token",
                refresh_token: refreshToken,
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: CLIENT_PASS
            }, 
            {headers: headers})
            .map( (response: Response) => {
                let token = response.json();
                if( token ) {
                    this.token = token.access_token;
                    localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN_LS_KEY, JSON.stringify({"access":this.token, "refresh":token.refresh_token}));
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            });
    }

    private createBearerTokenHeader(headers) {
        this.token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_LS_KEY));
        if( this.token ) {
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token.access);
        }
    }

    private createContentTypeHeader(headers) {
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    }
}
```

Requests are going fine with appropriate headers. The problem occurs when the access token is expired on server side the refresh token request sent perfectly and updates the access token and refresh token on local storage but i have to resend the request which was failed that didnt went again no error is displayed only the refresh token request went even the result condition is also matched but this.request call in intercept method didnt occur. What am i doing wrong?